# NeuralNetwork back propagation question

Tags: c, math, parallel-processing, neural-network, backpropagation

After reading a lot of other peoples neural network code I am convinced something is not right with my code. It works and I can train a network its just that in order to train the next perceptron in the hidden layer I must train the last one, shouldn't I be able to train all the units in a hidden layer in parallel?

Here is the code it calculates the error of the hidden layer:

```
    for(int i=n->numOfPerceptronLayers-2;i>=1;i--) { // for all hidden layers
        float sum = 0.0; // <- This here is the problem
        for(int j=0;j<n->perceptronLayers[i].numOfPerceptrons;j++) { // For all the units in the current hidden layer
            for(int k=0;k<n->perceptronLayers[i].perceptrons[j].numOfConnections;k++) { // Loop through the current units connections to the previous layer (output layer)
                sum += n->perceptronLayers[i+1].perceptrons[k].error * n->perceptronLayers[i+1].perceptrons[k].weights[j];
            }
            n->perceptronLayers[i].perceptrons[j].error = n->perceptronLayers[i].perceptrons[j].output * (1.0 - n->perceptronLayers[i].perceptrons[j].output) * sum;
        }
    }
```

It should be like this (but this doesn't work):

```
for(int i=n->numOfPerceptronLayers-2;i>=1;i--) { // for all hidden layers 
    for(int j=0;j<n->perceptronLayers[i].numOfPerceptrons;j++) { // For all the units in the current hidden layer
        float sum = 0.0;
        for(int k=0;k<n->perceptronLayers[i].perceptrons[j].numOfConnections;k++) { // Loop through the current units connections to the previous layer (output layer)
                sum += n->perceptronLayers[i+1].perceptrons[k].error * n->perceptronLayers[i+1].perceptrons[k].weights[j];
        }
        n->perceptronLayers[i].perceptrons[j].error = n->perceptronLayers[i].perceptrons[j].output * (1.0 - n->perceptronLayers[i].perceptrons[j].output) * sum;
    }
}
```

Why is it that the sum variable must be declared for the entire layer rather than a single perceptron?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what "it doesn't work" means. And could you add the exact mathematical formula you are trying to encode, because I have the impression something might get lost in translation here.

Comment: The mathematical formula is the back propagation learning, I am trying to calculate the errors of the perceptrons in the hidden layer. It doesn't work means that the training process does not work the network never learns what it is suppose to in the second piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I believe the *first* code segment is wrong, while the latter segment is correct.

In the first code segment, your use of a single 'sum' variable for a whole layer causes the error to accumulate with each subsequent perceptron dealt with. Thus, perceptron j will always have more error than perceptron j-1.

The latter code fixes this problem, but you say it is the one that isn't working. The only sound conclusion is that the real problem lies elsewhere in your code, as the first code segment *shouldn't* work.

Aside: you should indeed be able to train all of a layer's perceptrons in parallel, as each perceptron only relies on it's forward connections for its share of the error (in standard feed-forward back-propagation).

Comment: hmmmm... one thing i've noticed is that if i add sum *= j+1 after I calculate sum it works as weird as that is. Do you have any idea on which segment would be causing the problem? I understand you don't have my code but its probably most likely the segment that updates the weights right?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the problem, basically my TrainPerceptron(Perceptron* p, float error, float momentum) function that trains a single perceptron was given the error of the perceptron through an argument even though the Perceptron structure had an error property. I was passing in the error property to the function but I guess something was getting mixed up because after I removed that argument and just used the error stored in the Perceptron structure it worked.

Comment: I am glad you found it, although I sense you are counting on "it working" to tell you if you are making errors and I just want to warn you that that is a bad approach for mathematical problems like this. You should verify step by step that your code does exactly follow the formula. It might still "work" even though it is wrong. You might just be making a new network architecture that does learn something, but if you do that unconsciously you are bound to get very confused in the future. You should first review your code rather than test it, and then test it properly.

Comment: For example with known values for backpropagation learning. Take another software and run it with identical values to verify your algorithm is exact.